# Alterar o conteúdo do onclick conforme tamanho da página

Tags: jquery, html

Estou fazendo um projeto que algumas imagens tem tooltip, mas ele só aparece com o clique. O problema é que na versão mobile não está legal, então preciso abrir uma página nova com o conteúdo desse tooltip. Existe alguma maneira de alterar o conteúdo do onclick conforme o tamanho da página?

Ex:

No desktop seria:

```
<img src="img.jpg" onclick="abre o tooltip" />
```

E no mobile seria:

```
<img src="img.jpg" onclick="location.href='abre pagina'" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar desta forma

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" ); 
if (mq.matches) {
    // mostra imagem com o tootlip
}
else {
    // mostra imagem com link
}
```

Fonte: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/

Comment: Marta, vale a pena referir que isto é só para browsers "modernos", IE10+ por exemplo. De resto `+1`

Comment: Na verdade nem sabia disso, @Sergio. Obrigada!